# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1)) in cv::binary_op

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I've seen this question being asked, however, the answers did not help resolve my issue, so hoping someone can help me out. I'm building an adaptive skin detector, so I'm using a dataset to train a classifier on different skin colors. Then I'd like to use my webcam to be able to detect skin in the image. I'm getting the following error though when applying the predicted mask to the camera frame:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1)) in cv::binary_op, file ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp, line 241
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "skinDetectionBetter.py", line 80, in <module>
    skin = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=imgLabels)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:241: error: (-215) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function cv::binary_op
```

I've tried resizing my mask imgLabels to use 3 color channels (ex (480,640,3)), then tried resizing to use 1 color channel (ex (480,640,1)), however, I continue to get this error. As far as I can see, the imgLabels and frame both have shape of (480,640,3). Here's a snippet of my code.

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # reads in the current frame
    # .read() returns True if frame read correctly, and False otherwise
    ret, frame = camera.read()

    if ret:
        # reshape the frame to follow format of training data (rows*col, 3)
        data = np.reshape(frame, (frame.shape[0] * frame.shape[1], 3))
        predictedLabels = classifier.predict(data)   # output:  [2 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...]  and shape: (480,640,3)
        predictedMask = (-(predictedLabels - 1) + 1) * 255

        # the AND operator applies the skinMask to the image
        imgLabels = np.resize(predictedMask, (frame.shape[0], frame.shape[1], 3))            # ERROR HAPPENS WITH BELOW LINE
        skin = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=imgLabels)

        # show the skin in the image along with the mask, show images side-by-side
        cv2.imshow("images", np.hstack([frame, skin]))
```

Comment: Use `cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` to convert from 3 channel color to 1 channel gray image.

Comment: So, I changed:

    ret, frame = camera.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Then I pass in gray to the bitwise_and

    skin = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask=imgLabels)

Still getting the same error. Also tried passing in gray to the imgLabels resize instead of the frame var. Still seeing the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `imgLabels` is 3-channel, mask must be single channel. You need to do `imgLabels = cv2.cvtColor(imgLabels, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`.