# mask out the image in python

Tags: python, crop, mask

I have a binary mask and an image of the same size. I want to mask out the human. I used `np.multiply`, but it gives an image like below, but, I want the human, not white pixels!!: I ploted the mask and image. they are normal, but their multiplication is not as I expect.

[image]

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
masks32x32 = "./DATA/resized_masks/"
images500x500 = "./DATA/resized_imgs/"

masks = os.listdir(masks32x32)
images = os.listdir(images500x500)

for inx, img in enumerate(images):
    img_array = cv2.imread(images500x500+img)
    mask_array = cv2.imread(masks32x32+img)
    mask120x120 = cv2.resize(mask_array,(500,500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    mask120x120 = np.divide(mask120x120, 255)

    masked_image=np.multiply(img_array, mask120x120)
    cv2.imshow("image",masked_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Use `cv2.bitwise_and(img_array, img_array, mask=mask120x120)` instead of `np.multiply`.

Comment: This seems to be tagged incorrectly. Can you add the library he's using?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Abitbol. I solved the problem using this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165847/opencv-error-assertion-failed-mtype-cv-8u-mtype-cv-8s-mask-same)

I will post it here. Maybe it helps them. I corrected the code as below. It works fine now.

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
masks32x32 = "./DATA/resized_masks/"
images500x500 = "./DATA/resized_imgs/"

masks = os.listdir(masks32x32)
images = os.listdir(images500x500)

for inx, img in enumerate(images):
    img_array = cv2.imread(images500x500+img)
    mask_array = cv2.imread(masks32x32+img)
    mask500x500 = cv2.resize(mask_array,(500,500),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    print(mask500x500.shape)
    print(img_array.shape)

    mask500x500 = cv2.cvtColor(mask500x500, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #mask500x500 = np.divide(mask500x500, 255)
    mask500x500 = mask500x500.astype(np.uint8)
    masked_image=cv2.bitwise_and(img_array, img_array, mask=mask500x500)
    #masked_image=np.multiply(img_array, mask120x120)
    cv2.imshow("image",masked_image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```